# visual basic.. I want to make a TextBox2 visible when TextBox1.text = "SHUTDOWN"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba, string-comparison

In visual basic, 
I want to make a `TextBox2` visible when `TextBox1.Text = "SHUTDOWN"`

this is my code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                                     Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    AcceptButton = Button1
    If TextBox1.Text = "SHUTDOWN" Then
        TextBox2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but it's not working

note: there is no error message... and the textbox1 charachter casing is "upper" so it will be "SHUTDOWN" and not working means that when i write "SHUTDOWN" in textbox1, textbox2 don't become visible

Comment: any error message? it is case sensitive "SHUTDOWN" is not equal to "shutdown" in VB.

Comment: please specify what exactly do you enter in the `TextBox1`, and what exactly means "not working".

Comment: there is no error massage... and the textbox1 charachter casing is "upper" so it will be "SHUTDOWN"
and not working means that when i write "SHUTDOWN" in textbox1 the textbox2 dont become visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is case sensitive, that means that `shutdown` is not the same as `SHUTDOWN`. You can use [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the overload that takes a `StringComparison`:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Equals("SHUTDOWN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnorecase) Then
    TextBox2.Visible = True
End If
```

Another option in VB.NET only is to use [`OPTION Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx) on file- or on project level.

If you use this as first line in your file:

```
Option Compare Text
```

You get a case-insensitive comparison. However, i would prefer the .NET way.

> Text: Results in string comparisons based on a case-insensitive text sort
>   order determined by your system's locale. This type of comparison is
>   useful if your strings contain all text characters, and you want to
>   compare them taking into account alphabetic equivalences such as case
>   insensitivity and closely related letters. For example, you might want
>   to consider A and a to be equal, and Ä and ä to come before B and b.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Textbox2.visible = False

End Sub


Protected Sub TxtBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtBox1.TextChanged
    If TxtBox1.Text.ToUpper = "SHUTDOWN" Then
       TextBox2.Visible = True
    Else
       TextBox2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the case of your text (if that is the problem) you could use the following:

```
If TextBox1.Text.ToUpper() = "SHUTDOWN" Then
    TextBox2.Visible = True
End If
```

also be sure your `TextBox2` has the right *coordinates* when became visible.

Comment: did you try to put a breakpoint to the line "If TextBox1.Text.ToUpper() = "SHUTDOWN" Then"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Wrd As String = "SHUTDOWN"
Protected Sub TxtBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtBox1.TextChanged
        If Wrd = TxtBox1.Text.ToUpper Then
            TxtBox5.Visible = True
         End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did a test with:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If (TextBox1.Text = "SHUTDOWN") Then
        TextBox2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Found no problems - it may be AcceptButton = Button1. I'm not sure why it isn't working but mine is working when "SHUTDOWN" is entered. Try changing the AcceptButton to a comment (') and then trying the code, if it works then its the AcceptButton variable.

May not be declared probably to store a button?